# Cannot get 4th vector to render in WebGL TRIANGLE_STRIP

Tags: webgl

I am trying to play around with WebGL and I can render a triangle in [this plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/YiIHKTLQ3KURdtrL1ubY?p=preview). Now I try to make this a full square by changing...

```
//This...
this.triangleVertexPositionBuffer.numItems = 3;
// ...
this.gl.drawArrays(this.gl.TRIANGLE_STRIP, 0, this.triangleVertexPositionBuffer.numItems);
// To this..
this.triangleVertexPositionBuffer.numItems = 4;
```

This to me should just make a square, however, the triangle completely disappears. I also get the following warning...

```
GL ERROR :GL_INVALID_OPERATION : glDrawArrays: attempt to access out of range vertices in attribute 1
```

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add a color attribute for your fourth vertex aswell.

Comment: Yup. Set `this.triangleVertexPositionBuffer.numItems` to `4` like in the question, but also add another row to `colors[]` in `initBuffers()`. Your fourth vertex want to draw just fine.